# compare the expiration date in /etc/shadow to today's date and figure out which accounts have expired

Tags: linux, ocelot

```
root@node033:~# vi exppass
root@node033:~# bash exppass
exppass: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file
root@node033:~# cat exppass
cat /etc/shadow |
while IFS=":" read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col8;
do
echo $col3 $col8 
if [ $expire -lt $today ];
then
```

I am trying to remove the expiration passwd using to compare the date and time.
adjust your script to do something along the lines:

```
if [ $expire -lt $today ]; then        
#delete the password
```

I think `$expire` above is equivalent to one of the columns you're reading. and you can get today's date by doing something like `today=$(date +%s)`

Comment: exppass: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
exppass: line 6: `done'
root@node033:~# cat exppass
cat /etc/shadow
while IFS=":" read col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
do
        echo $expire $today
        if [$expire -lt $today ];
done

Comment: Read up on the shadow file, and its format. You will see what each column is for.  But there are commands to do that, you should not have to parse shadow for anything ever.  Do some research based on your flavor of linux.  See https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-howto-check-user-password-expiration-date-and-time/ for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're happy w/ an `awk` & `bash` solution rather than doing the hard lifting in a loop:

```
awk -F: -v today=$(( $( date "+%s" ) / 86400 ))  '$8!=""{print $1, today-$8}' /etc/shadow
```

Explanation:
`-F:` defines the input field separator to be a colon.

`-v today=$(( $( date "+%s" ) / 86400 ))` expresses today's date in days since epoch (which is the format used in `/etc/shadow`) and assigns it to an `awk` variable called `today`.

Now for the awk logic:

`$8!=""` if the 8th field (Account Expiry) isn't unset, `{print $1, today-$8}` print the username and the difference between today and the expiry date in days. If the date lies in the past, you get a positive value, if it's in the future, a negative one.

**Edit**:

Looking at the jumble above it appears that you're trying to check for both password and account expiry:

This should do:

```
awk -F: -v today=$(( $( date "+%s" ) / 86400 ))  '$3!="" || $8!=""{printf "%s\tpw: %s\tacc: %s\n", $1,today - $3, today-$8}' /etc/shadow
```

The 2nd field now shows the age of the password, the 3rd the account expiration. If this still isn't what you're after you'll need to sit down and rephrase your question so it reflects what you're actually after.

Comment: t8391:$y$j9T$mdmVXUNYpz5iKbxWn1XLn.$.Cpexmko1kRQUPC7dfW3g9D/Plsh1ruWOXc/yYPUEi.:19404:0:99999:7::19564:
bn5424:$y$j9T$bZX10lFFtIiGrrSkZYd2b0$wuR3Owdk1exTwq3vVl9iXT0yC.XlR5d1Rx0lN01wiN1:19404:0:99999:7::19214:
nm5699:$y$j9T$x62nrTE14nz3ALVK09n4f0$YIo8g4oWmaxlY6r/y3Mfa3HaYqMCh2S74ikafeO4RK8:19404:0:99999:7::19594:
root@node033:~#

Comment: Thank you for sharing password hashes and stuff  -  what are you trying to tell me? @AnaC

Comment: root@node033:~# cat /etc/shadow | wc -l
1033 (The number indicates that the passwd was not removed)

Comment: You were talking about account expiration, not passwords, in your title. Just change both occurrences of `$8` to `$3`.

Comment: the output is username and 1 all of them

Comment: still hve 1033 usernames with old account or expired passwd

Comment: how can I remove the old account?

Comment: By "old" you mean accounts that have password. account or both expired? @AnaC

Comment: @AnaC - and a second thought. None of the accounts you posted have a useful max_age set, so checking the "last changed date" makes no sense - it will be the time of user creation (most likely) and all of them will be lower than "today" unless you only want to give people access on the day you're checking.